# More elegant way for solving $y(x) = y_{1}(x) + y_{2}(x)$ in $y'' - 10y' + 28y = 29xe^{-x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a more elegant way for solving $y(x) = y_{1}(x) + y_{2}(x)$ in $y'' - 10y' + 28y = 29xe^{-x}$ than to use Euler's identity and get the general solution through brute computation?

Comment: I think the standard way of solving this type of linear equations is by finding a general solution to the homogenious equation (via characteristic polynomial) plus a particular solution (via substitution $y(x)=z(x)e^{-x}$).

Comment: Just as A.G. commented, there is no other way for the  homogenous equation. You reduce the  *brute force* using the obvious substitution.

Comment: what do you mean with more elegant way?

Comment: for the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_p=(Ax+B)e^{-x}$$ with the real numbers $$A,B$$